# How can I migrate/copy a build history multipipeline from old branch to new branch

Tags: jenkins, deployment, build, jenkins-pipeline, branch

fellas.

How's it going?

I've this situation: Is it possible migrate/copy a build history multipipeline from old branch to New branch?

It's a migrate branch, the Jenkins Server will be the same and Job too.

It is necessary because all jenkinsfiles create a package using CurrentBuild.number.

I've been trying some classes like getLastBuild, getLastCompleteBuild, but just return build number and not the build history.